# Microsoft Access and Visual Basic - Need help running module

Tags: vba, ms-access

I need help with a microsoft access application I am trying to create.
I created a database that gets a number of dates.  I need to count the number of days between the dates, and OMIT Tuesdays, Thursdays, Saturdays and Sundays in the counter. This is between two separate time intervals (NotificationDate to OrderDate) and (PlacementDate to ReleaseDate)

My question is, now that I wrote it, how do I actually use it in Microsoft Access?? How do I run it from a form?

```
'//////This is for Valley Estimate of Demurrage Days/////////////
Public Function Weekdays(ByRef NotificationDate As Date, ByRef OrderDate As Date, ByRef PlacementDate As Date, ByRef ReleaseDate As Date) As Integer
Dim numWeekdays As Integer
Dim totalDays As Integer
Dim totaldays2 As Integer
Dim WeekendDays As Integer
Dim WeekendDays2 As Integer
numWeekdays = 0
WeekendDays = 0
WeekendDays2 = 0

totalDays = DateDiff(dateinterval.Day, NotificationDate, OrderDate) + 1

'for i as integer = 1 to totalDays

    If DatePart(dateinterval.Weekday, NotificationDate) = 1 Then
        WeekendDays = WeekendDays + 1
    End If
    If DatePart(dateinterval.Weekday, startDateNotificationDate) = 3 Then
        WeekendDays = WeekendDays + 1
    End If
    If DatePart(dateinterval.Weekday, NotificationDate) = 5 Then
        WeekendDays = WeekendDays + 1
    End If
    If DatePart(dateinterval.Weekday, NotificationDate) = 7 Then
        WeekendDays = WeekendDays + 1
    End If
        NotificationDate = DateAdd("d", 1, NotificationDate)
        '///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

 totaldays2 = DateDiff(dateinterval.Day, PlacementDate, ReleaseDate) + 1

    If DatePart(dateinterval.Weekday, PlacementDate) = 1 Then
        WeekendDays2 = WeekendDays2 + 1
    End If
    If DatePart(dateinterval.Weekday, PlacementDate) = 3 Then
        WeekendDays2 = WeekendDays2 + 1
    End If
    If DatePart(dateinterval.Weekday, PlacementDate) = 5 Then
        WeekendDays2 = WeekendDays2 + 1
    End If
    If DatePart(dateinterval.Weekday, PlacementDate) = 7 Then
        WeekendDays2 = WeekendDays2 + 1
    End If
        PlacementDate = DateAdd("d", 1, PlacementDate)

                    numWeekdays = WeekendDays + WeekendDays2                                                

End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can show the result of an expression by entering it in the `ControlSource` of a `TextBox`. Prepend it with "=".

```
=Weekdays(CDate([txtNotificationDate]), CDate([txtOrderDate]),
CDate([txtPlacementDate]), CDate([txtReleaseDate]))
```

(on one line)

Note that you can access the TextBoxes (and other controls of the current Form) by just entering their names in the expression. Access will add the brackets [] automatically.

If Access should not update the result TextBox automatically, you can force the recalculation of it with

```
Me!txtResult.Requery
```

But in most situations Access will update it automatically.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot, this is more along the lines of what I am looking for.  I'll test it out now

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend changing the function name to `ModWeekdays`.  That way you know it is defined in a module.  Also, I think the function `Weekdays` is already defined.

Then you already have the function set as ***Public***, so all you have to do is something like the following:

```
Dim MyReturnVal As Integer
MyReturnVal = ModWeekdays(txtNotificationDate, txtOrderDate, txtPlacementDate, txtReleaseDate)
```

Also, you do not need to pass all your variables to the function by reference since you are not changing them.  So instead I would use:

```
Public Function ModWeekdays(ByRef NotificationDate As Date, OrderDate As Date, ByRef PlacementDate As Date, ReleaseDate As Date) As Integer
```

**EDIT**, here is the code I used in your modified MS Access file:

```
Private Sub cmdSubmit_Click()
  On Error GoTo Err_cmdSubmit
  Dim MyReturnVal As Integer

  If (IsNull(txtNotificationDate)) Then GoTo Err_DataMissing
  If (IsNull(txtOrderDate)) Then GoTo Err_DataMissing
  If (IsNull(txtPlacementDate)) Then GoTo Err_DataMissing
  If (IsNull(txtReleaseDate)) Then GoTo Err_DataMissing

  If (IsDate(txtNotificationDate) = False) Then GoTo Err_DataType
  If (IsDate(txtOrderDate) = False) Then GoTo Err_DataType
  If (IsDate(txtPlacementDate) = False) Then GoTo Err_DataType
  If (IsDate(txtReleaseDate) = False) Then GoTo Err_DataType

  MyReturnVal = ModWeekdays(txtNotificationDate, txtOrderDate, txtPlacementDate, txtReleaseDate)
  MsgBox ("The value returned from the ModWeekdays function is:  " & MyReturnVal)

Exit_cmdSubmit:
  Exit Sub
Err_cmdSubmit:
  MsgBox Err.Description
  Resume Exit_cmdSubmit
Err_DataMissing:
  MsgBox ("You must supply a value for the Notification Date, Order Date, Placement Date, and Release Date.")
  GoTo Exit_cmdSubmit
Err_DataType:
  MsgBox ("You must enter Dates only.  Please correct and try again.")
  GoTo Exit_cmdSubmit
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the "txt" in "txtNotificationDate"?

Comment: That is just referencing a control on a form for instance.  `txtNotificationDate` would be the name of the control which should contain the notification date.  You could use any variable name or hard code the date like `'05/05/14'`.

Comment: I appreciate your help but perhaps my misunderstanding is more fundamental.  After I enter what you suggested, (MyReturnVal) how can I now view that in an Access Form?  Also, I have the variables NotificationDate, OrderDate, etc which are inputted by the user in the standard access view, so how can I "link" this to the variables in my VBA code?  here is a link to my access program: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2aq4WToAF2YN2lkNEsyeWZna0k/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Check out the following modification of your database [**Google Doc**](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxCQ7z_yTEoxb3ZpZFczSTktcFE/edit?usp=sharing).  If you run the ***Test*** from enter and hit the Submit button.  let me know if that helps you.

Comment: Sorry about that, it is set to public now.